# Create a bootable USB drive for Windows

Tags: usb, windows

I'm trying to make a bootable USB for Windows 7 in Ubuntu (14.04) any ideas on how to do this? I've been searching but all of the other questions are talking about creating an Ubuntu USB. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WinUSB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winusb/), a program especially created for that, you just input your ISO and specify a USB or CD device to output on. Older versions of [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) also support this, but newer versions don't.

Comment: I tried this, but with the WinUSB when is almost done I get an error, something about the GRUB

Comment: Well, GRUB is a bootloader, it's probably something with your computer

Answer (score 1):

1) make one partition, format as NTFS & mark bootable
2) write boot sector (ms-sys -7)
3) mount and copy all the files from the iso

Details on how to do the three steps
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=163574

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but you could run the 'startup disk creator' in Ubuntu, and use your Windows iso for the input file.

Alternatively, and this is a longer work around, you could use your Windows ISO to create a virtual machine in Ubuntu, and from the virtual machine use Windows applications to create the USB.

Answer (score 0):

To create Bootable for windows 7 install unetbootin:-

click here to download unetbootin: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

You can even download from Ubuntu Software Center. Just search 'unetbootin'.
[image]

Visit here for detailed information:- http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html

Comment: This doesn't work, I cannot choose the USB drive

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create a live USB like you can do with Ubuntu and friends.

you can use any Virtual Machine,format your USB drive to NTFS,mount your USB drive to the virtual machine as a HDD,install it you your USB from the virtual machine

Cheers :)

P.S. : You need at least 16 GB of USB drive.